# How to use coalesce function in Django ORM?

Tags: python-3.x, django, coalesce

I have a sql query whose `coalesce` portion that looks like below

```
"coalesce(MAX(case when status = 'OK' then 'OK' end),'') as final_status"
```

I am writing the same query in Django ORM. But I am not getting any value for the `coalesce` portion. This is how the `coalesce` portion looks like

```
    .annotate(final_status=Max(Coalesce(
        Case(
            When(status__contains=['OK'], then=Value('OK')),
            default=Value(''),
            output_field=CharField()
        ),
        Case(
            When(~Q(notify__contains=['OK']), then=Value('')),
            default=Value(''),
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    )))
```

In regular sql query, I am getting values in `final_status` column but in django query, the `final_status` column is empty for all the rows

What am I doing wrong?